# Are there digital (industrial) cameras with open API's (software interfaces) with Ethernet communication?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera

Dear Photography Community,

I realize that some SE sites do not allow specific product recommendations, and that's ok.

I'm concerned that after my fruitless searching, I'm perhaps missing some appropriate keywords or even entire segments of the industry.  I definitely have more to learn.

With that being said:
I'm part of a small company that has a need to acquire color digital images under these conditions:

- Color images, 1.5 to N Megapixels (where N < 10-ish).  Our current solution is 1.5 MP.
- Camera-to-subject distance of ~ 6-12 inches (150 - 300 mm).
- Minimal image/edge distortion.  Can crop in post...
- Field of view like a few inches horizontally & vertically hoped for.
- Remote-input settable focus distance (perhaps via communication interface). Auto-focus has been problematic for us b/c the subject can be rather featureless.
- Ethernet interface, with an open protocol/API to use with our software (OS happens to Linux).
- Integral lighting (preferably), natural light color temp.
- Small, rigidly mounted, form-factor.  Like 2"x2"x6" or such.
- Low image acquisition rate: we'd need only 1 image every 5 seconds or so.

We do **not** need many of the 'smart camera' features found with many industrial camera offerings, like:
Part counting, recognition, measuring, learning, annotating, web connectivity, offsite servers...

Often times these 'features' make the camera (and the expensive required software that comes along with it) less accessible to us.

Our goals to be able to acquire a nice, relatively flat/un-distorted, true-color image of a thing that's a few (variable) inches away.

I would be overjoyed with <del>specific solutions</del>, **search suggestions, general guidelines, and pointers**.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but this does fall squarely into our bucket of off-topic due to being a straight up product recommendation question.

Comment: Let's try to keep this open, the answer could be in a type of camera, not a specific model or brand.

Comment: What is "true color" in this context?

Comment: @mattdm  I've seen offerings where the sensor is b&w, and/or one needs to use RBG filters.  There are also IR and near UV versions.  We're interested in the visible/color spectrum.

Comment: Okay. I was concerned you were looking for a particular color response directly from the sensor (something atypical of consumer cameras).

Comment: Is this for an industrial or computer vision application as suggested by the title and requirements?

Comment: @xiota An application where a photo of the subject object is taken as a record as part of an existing 2D (Gantry table) robotic platform.  An unknown number of targets, of unknown size,  are placed in a 2D space.  Large targets have their images stitched together, while small targets may need only 1 frame.  We utilize our own stitching software.

Comment: @xiota Yes, this should be considered an industrial application.  However, I've had issues with the "Computer Vision" phrase, as there's no required integrated 'smarts' required for this application.  Just the acquisition of images.

Comment: Perhaps this should be migrated to robotics.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @xiota  Re:Migration.  I'm game... I've done a fair bit of searching.  However I suspected that there may be 'photographic' terms that I may be missing - as I'm not familiar with most of the technical aspects of photography.  Like phrases dealing with specifications for our application, and form factor.

Comment: Even though you don't "need" the "smart" features, computer vision related devices seem like they'd fit your needs, especially since you want something programmable.  The "smarts" in computer vision can be external to the camera.

Comment: To what extent are you willing to assemble or build things yourself vs have an all-in-one solution?  What aspects of the camera need to be "programmable"?  What needs to be communicated with the camera?  Why ethernet (vs wireless vs USB)?

Comment: @xiota Rather a all-in-one.  Programming: Focus distance has historically been the only required programmable aspect. Communication: Set focus to *this*, and Acquire picture.  Ethernet:  The electrically superior interface that supports long cable lengths with built-in (by default) electrical isolation.  It's also very easy to program for.  Usb can introduce ground loops and has serious cable length issues.  We also use HP desktops, and there's something about HP and their USB interface that really blows (at the hardware/firmware level). We are aware, and have used active USB extension cables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are many systems that might be useful for you. [GigE Vision](https://www.visiononline.org/vision-standards-details.cfm?type=5) and [GenICam](https://www.emva.org/standards-technology/genicam/) are the standards that you are looking for. Individual manufacturers that support this standard have an API that you can use for your purposes.

There are multiple manufacturers that produce the type of the cameras that you want. But the best approach would be to handle the illumination system externally according to your needs.

I am not affiliated with any of the companies here. Some example camera models:

- Basler ace 2 series https://www.baslerweb.com/en/products/cameras/area-scan-cameras/ace2/a2a1920-51gcbas/
- JAI 3-sensor models if you want very accurate colors: https://www.jai.com/products/area-scan-cameras/3-sensor-r-g-b-prism

Answer (score 1):

A really quick search came up with [Programmable Motorized Focus Camera Raspberry Pi now Supports Auto Focus](https://www.arducam.com/programmable-motorized-focus-camera-raspberry-pi/). There are a bunch of things like this, and combining with a small ARM computer like the Pi seems like it can easily cover your other needs. This isn't an endorsement of that particular model, just an example of the kind of thing you should look for.

The one concern might be:

> Minimal image/edge distortion. Can crop in post...

... because these are all going to be pretty cheap, simple lens assemblies. But given your very modest resolution needs, *this should be fine*, because you can characterize the specific distortion of the camera model you choose and use something like the [Lensfun library](https://lensfun.github.io/) to correct as part of your capture/processing pipeline.

Comment: I'll consider this.  We've had past experiences with pi's, beagles, and arduino's.  I'd rather not have to manufacture enclosures, and keep up with constantly changing software and firmware (and even circuit boards).  However, this solution is on my list of possibilities.  Thanks for the Lensfun link.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements sound very much like that of a "**Security Camera**"                        or a "**Borescope**".

Answer (score 0):

One useful search term to find something like this would be "remote controlled video camera".  One of the top results of that search found me this page:

https://pro.sony/en_NZ/products/robotic-cameras

This camera looks like it might be suitable for you -- the only thing missing is built-in illumination, which you noted as optional

https://pro.sony/en_NZ/products/robotic-cameras/srg-300se#TEME501823SimultaneousStreaming-srg-300se

Comment: Thanks Nate,  I'll look into it.  The robotic aspect of the camera mounts are not needed for our application.

Comment: That's true, but I think you'll have a hard time finding remotely controllable focus without pan/tilt/zoom also being remotely controllable -- it's a fairly niche use case.  Whereas this type of camera are very common for situations where high quality video is needed from a location where you can't physically fit a person.